# Можно ли явно вызвать clock_gettime через vdso?

Tags: linux, c, системное-программирование, syscall

Моему приложению нужно часто вызывать clock_gettime, для получения времени в наносекундах, к сожалению, этот системный вызов крайне медленный, по идее система по умолчанию должна использовать vdso для данного системного вызова, но судя по всему этого не происходит, и осуществляется переключение контекста в режим ядра. Можно ли явно указать системному вызову использовать vdso, или напрямую сделать системный вызов через vdso?

Comment: Покажи вывод `sudo cat /proc/1/maps -vv`

Comment: @ori,
7ffea53af000-7ffea53d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffea53e0000-7ffea53e4000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffea53e4000-7ffea53e6000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 --xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

Comment: А если на запущенном процессе, твоей программы, что там выведет, просто говорится о том что `glibc` автоматически его должен использовать.

Comment: Приложение, которое доверяет наносекундам, *получаемым от ОС*, это уже нонсенс. Задумайтесь об этом.

Comment: @avp А если это специальная real-time ОС?

Comment: @avp, в любом случае я нашел решение, vdso вариантом является вызов с флагом CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE, но точность меньше

Comment: @Mikhailo, тогда нужно надеяться, что она предоставляет доступ прямо к регистрам таймера (или счетчику тактов процессора) / Кстати, чтение регистра "по общей шине" вполне может вылиться в сотню-другую нан (при доступе к L1 кэшу в пару нан)

Comment: @avp, в RTOS, особенно на одноядерных процессорах — это нормально. В любом случае погрешность там перекроет точность, а относительные данные как-то можно использовать.